Conditional expectation of exponential random variable given minimum of sample
Suppose $X_1, \dots , X_n \sim f_{\theta}(x) = e^{-(x-\theta)}$ are IID.
I'm interested in the conditional expectation $E[X_1 | X_{(1)} = t]$, where $X_{(1)} = \min(X_1, \dots, X_n)$.
Let $f_{X_1|T} (x|t)$ be the conditional pdf of $X_1$ given $X_{(1)} = t$. By definition:
\begin{equation}
f_{X_1|T} (x|t) = \frac{f_{X_1,T} (x,t)}{f_T(t)}
\end{equation}
I have $f_T(t) = ne^{-n(t-\theta)}$ for $t \in (\theta, \infty)$.
For the joint pdf $f_{X_1,T}$ I consider two cases.
If $X_1 = X_{(1)}$, then I argue $f_{X_1,T}(x,t)$ is $0$ almost everywhere because it only has support on the diagonal where $x=t$.
If $X_1 \neq X_{(1)}$, then $X_{(1)}$ is some $X_i$ for $i \neq 1$ and thus $X_1, X_{(1)}$ are independent. In this case the joint pdf splits:
\begin{equation}
f_{X_1|T} (x|t) = \frac{f_\theta(x)f_T(t)}{f_T(t)} = f_\theta(x)
\end{equation}
Thus $E[X_1 | X_{(1)} = t] = E[X_1] = \int_{\theta}^\infty xe^{-(x-\theta)}dx = [-xe^{-(x-\theta)} - e^{-(x-\theta)}]_\theta^\infty = \theta + 1$.
Intuitively, this would mean knowing the minimum of the sample doesn't give me any information about $X_1$.
Is this argument correct?

Three mistakes: 1. If $X_1 = X_{(1)}$, then $X_1 = t$; we can't just ignore that case.  2. If $X_1\neq X_{(1)}$, this doesn't make $X_1$ and $X_{(1)}$ independent; in particular, we know that $X_1 > X_{(1)}$.  (A hint for this part is to use the memoryless property of the exponential.)  3. By your reasoning, you need to split $E[X_1\mid X_{(1)} = t]$ into the conditions where $X_1 = X_{(1)}$ and $X_1 \neq X_{(1)}$ using the law of total expectation.

I'd recommend doing sanity checks on your solution.  Like if $t > \theta +1$, then this answer obviously doesn't make sense (how could the expectation of $X_1$ given the minimum be less than the minimum?).

There is no joint density of $(X_1,X_{(1)})$ in the usual sense (with respect to Lebesgue measure) because $X_1=X_{(1)}$ occurs with a positive probability of $\frac1n$.
Here, as @user806050 suggests, you can use the law of total expectation.
For any $t\in [\theta,\infty)$, you have
\begin{align}
E\left[X_1\mid X_{(1)}=t\right]&=E\left[X_1\mid X_1=t\right]\cdot\frac1n + E\left[X_1\mid X_1>t\right]\cdot\left(1-\frac1n\right)
\\&=\frac{t}{n}+(1+t)\left(1-\frac1n\right)
\\&=t+1-\frac1n.
\end{align}
That $E\left[X_1\mid X_1>t\right]=1+t$ can be shown directly from $E\left[X_1\mid X_1>t\right]=\frac{E\left[X_1\mathbf1_{X_1>t}\right]}{P(X_1>t)}$ or equivalently by noting that the conditional distribution of $X_1$ given $X_1>t$ is another shifted exponential with shift $t$:
$$f_{X_1\mid X_1>t}(x)=e^{-(x-t)}\mathbf1_{x>t}.$$
Hence, $$E\left[X_1\mid X_{(1)}\right]=X_{(1)}+1-\frac1n \quad,\text{ a.e. }$$
There are also other indirect ways of finding this conditional expectation (compare with Computing the UMVUE for Uniform$(0,\theta)$). For more formal derivations, have a look at Finding an efficient estimator for $\theta$ in $U[0, \theta]$ in terms of the sample maximum and Finding $E(|X_1|\ |\max |X_i| )$ for similar discussions on a $\text{Uniform}(0,\theta)$ model.
Edit:
In case it is not clear, the law of total expectation is used in the following way:
$$E\left[X_1\mid X_{(1)}=t\right]=E\left[X_1\mid X_{(1)}=t,A \right]P(A\mid X_{(1)}=t)+E\left[X_1\mid X_{(1)}=t,A^c\right]P(A^c\mid X_{(1)}=t)\,,$$ where $A$ is the event $\{X_1=X_{(1)}\}$.

As an aside, here $X_1-X_{(1)}$ happens to be independent of $X_{(1)}$, which can be argued using Basu's theorem. This immediately gives $$E\left[X_1\mid X_{(1)}\right]=E\left[X_1-X_{(1)}\mid X_{(1)}\right]+X_{(1)}=E\left[X_1-X_{(1)}\right]+X_{(1)}\,,$$ and all that remains is to find $E\left[X_1\right]$ and $E\left[X_{(1)}\right]$.

Could you please explain how we know $P[X_1 = X_{(1)}] = \frac{1}{n}$? Is it because the $X_i$ are IID and thus each one has an equal chance of being the smallest?

It is because $X_i$'s are iid and continuous.

I have $P[X_1 = X_{(1)}] = P[X_2 > X_1 , \dots , X_n > X_1] = \int_\theta^\infty P[X_2 > x , \dots , X_n > x] dx$ but the computation is giving me $\frac{1}{n-1}$...not sure where I am going wrong

@Bastiza You could say $P[X_1 = X_{(1)}] = \int_\theta^\infty P[X_2 > x , \dots , X_n > x] , f(x) , dx$ $= \int_\theta^\infty \left(e^{-(x-\theta)}\right)^{n-1}, e^{-(x-\theta)}, dx$ $= \int_\theta^\infty e^{-n(x-\theta)}, dx $ $=\frac1n$ though the exchangeability argument may be faster

@Henry Makes sense, I forgot the $f(x)$ term, I guess that is the "$P[X_1=x]$" part

The formula:
$$E\left[X_1\mid X_{(1)}=t\right]=E\left[X_1\mid X_1=t\right]\cdot\frac1n + E\left[X_1\mid X_1>t\right]\cdot\left(1-\frac1n\right)$$
is difficult to understand, can it be demonstrated?

@Speltzu Conditioning on the minimum $X_{(1)}=t$, then either $X_1=X_{(1)}=t$ with probability $\frac1n$ or $X_1>X_{(1)}=t$  with probability $1-\frac1n$.

I still don't understand. What formula or theorem applies?

Right, but then we will have to prove that $E[X_1\mid X_{(1)}=t, A]=E[X_1\mid X_1=t]$ and $E[X_1\mid X_{(1)}=t, A^c]=E[X_1\mid X_1>t]$.

@Speltzu $E[X_1\mid X_{(1)}=t,A]=E[X_1\mid X_1=t,X_{(1)}=t]=E[X_1\mid X_1=t]$. You need to ask a separate question if your query persists.

Then $E[X_1\mid X_{(1)}=t,X_2= X_{(1)}]=E[X_1\mid X_2=t,X_{(1)}=t] = E[X_1\mid X_2=t]$?.

You are right:
$P(X_1-X_{(1)}\in A\mid X_{(1)})=\frac{1}{n}I_A(0)+\frac{n-1}{n}\int_A e^{-x}dx$
